# MySQL: Get total in detail page and summary page

Tags: mysql

My data looks like this:

```
UserID  Hours   BillRate
1   1.50    2.25
1   2.50    3.25
1   3.50    3.25
2   5.50    4.25
2   6.50    5.25
2   7.50    5.25
```

In detail page, I have this query to get total spend for each UserID

```
SELECT UserID, ROUND(SUM(Hours*BillRate), 2) AS TotalSpend
FROM mytable
GROUP BY UserID
```

The result is 22.88 for UserID_1 and 96.88 for UserID_2 (the total is **119.76**)

In summary page, I have to run a query with 2 SELECT statements to get the right total:

```
SELECT SUM(TotalSpend)
FROM (
    SELECT UserID, ROUND(SUM(Hours*BillRate), 2) AS TotalSpend
    FROM mytable
    WHERE UserID IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY UserID
) a
```

Is there anyway that i can get the total in summary page with **one SELECT statement**?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(Hours*BillRate), 2) AS TotalSpend
FROM mytable
WHERE UserID IN (1, 2)
```

Comment: juergen: i tried that query before posted the question here.  The query gives me the wrong result... 119.75.  I need to be 119.76

Comment: Oops, the `WITH ROLLUP` answer that I posted also has that problem. Rounding the sum of rounded values causes error propagation, are you sure you really want to do that?

Comment: Barmar: thanks for your answer, that extra row shows the right total.  But I need the result in one row.  I don't want to modify my code much...

Comment: Actually, it's the sum of rounded values.  It's not "rounding the sum of rounded values"...

Comment: i take it back, you're right.  WITH ROLLUP also has the problem

Comment: Barmar: do you have any suggestion?